# No me toma el ajax al presionar el boton

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Al momento de presionar el boton. no me toma la función de ajax nisiquiera un error me manda en la consola. El codigo es el siguiente

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        let Myjsonpana = "hola";
        $("#todo_bien").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?&page=retail/actions/egg',
            data: Myjsonpana,
            success: function(){
                alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
            },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Y el boton es el siguiente.

```
<a id="todo_bien" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Confirmar</a>
```

el data es solo un simple texto para ver si tomaba, pero aun así no me toma nada.

Comment: Asegurate que el URL sea el correcto

Answer (score 0):

En el campo data del AJAX tienes que colocarlo como un JSON, de tal forma quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        let Myjsonpana = "hola";
        $("#todo_bien").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?&page=retail/actions/egg',
            data: {
            "Myjsonpana": Myjsonpana
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
            },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```